# Javascript object with arrays to search param style query string

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string

Looking for clean way to convert a javascript object containing arrays as values to a search param compatible query string. Serializing an element from each array before moving to the next index.

Using libraries such as querystring or qs, converts the object just fine, but handles each array independently. Passing the resulting string to the server (which I cannot change) causes an error in handling of the items as each previous value is overwritten by the next. Using any kind of array notation in the query string is not supported. The only option I have not tried is a custom sort function, but seems like it would be worse than writing a custom function to parse the object. Any revision to the object that would generate the expected result is welcome as well.

```
var qs = require("qs")
var jsobj = {
    origString:['abc','123'],
    newString:['abcd','1234'],
    action:'compare'
}
qs.stringify(jsobj,{encode:false})
qs.stringify(jsobj,{encode:false,indices:false})
qs.stringify(jsobj,{encode:false,indices:false,arrayFormat:'repeat'})
```

Result returned is

```
"origString=abc&origString=123&newString=abcd&newString=1234&action=compare"
```

Result desired would be

```
"origString=abc&newString=abcd&origString=123&newString=1234&action=compare"
```

Comment: Why does the order matter ?

Comment: *"causes an error in handling of the items as each previous value is overwritten by the next."* How is that related to the order of the query string? It seems the server is not able to understand that parameters with the same name should be put into an array. Which language is running on the server? PHP needs `[]` after the parameter names.

Comment: Server is using Java. It is a very poorly written piece of software hence the efforts to work around it. When I tried the post request with duplicate names and no `[]` only the last value was retrieved. Submitting with `[]` just breaks the request entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reorder your json:

```
> var jsobj = [{origString: 'abc', newString: 'abcd' }, {origString: '123', 
newString: '1234' }, {action:'compare'}]
> qs.stringify(jsobj,{encode:false})
'0[origString]=abc&0[newString]=abcd&1[origString]=123&1[newString]=1234&2[action]=compare'
```

But I don't know if this is a good alternative for your problem.

Comment: I had come across this idea myself earlier while trying to figure this out, originally I didn't think it would work since it has a form of array notation, however it escapaced me to just use regex to remove that.
`str.replace(/[0-9]\[|]/g,''))`
This will return the string I need. Thanks for helping me see that. Leaving this open incase there is another option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this up to misunderstanding of the application. After spending some more time with the API I realized my mistake, and as posted above by others, order does no matter. Not sure why my first several attempts failed but the question is 'answered'